# At what dp screen width does the action bar not split when android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" is set?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I'm really after the screen config qualifiers that would be picked when the screen is wide enough for the split action bar to not split.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the screens width (in the current rotation) is bigger than 480dp then Android won't use the split ActionBar.

See [this](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/c8dce8966b84203befb87a24a9d2d8ee87a39f7b/core/res/res/values-w480dp/bools.xml#L21) boolean value from the framework.

**Edit:**

`splitActionBarWhenNarrow` has been [deprecated](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/11/18/android-5p0-deprecation-splitactionbarwhennarrow.html).

Comment: The resource you are linking does not use the smallest-width qualifier, but just "width". That actually makes sense, because the splitActionBarWhenNarrow property is affected by configuration changes.